# convert this while loop to a more efficient while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to work this out is the simplest way, i am a beginner, this is the question i have been asked and the code:

Program logic alternatives. Consider the following code, which uses a while loop and found flag to search a list of powers of 2 for the value of 2 raised to the fifth power(32) It's stored in a module file called power.py.

```
L = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
X = 5
found = False
i = 0

while not found and i < len(L):
    `if 2 ** X == L[i]:`
        found = True
    else:
        i = i+1

if found:
    ('at index', i)
else:
     print(X,'not found')
```

The question it asked me to do is a couple but the first one is confusing me,

a.)First, rewrite the code with a while loop else clause to eliminate the found flag and final if statement.

Any help is appreciated please. Thanks.

Comment: #1 Rewrite the code without a `found` variable. #2 Rewrite the code so the only if statement is inside the while loop (this must be done as a result of #1) ... are you allowed the use of functions?

Comment: Doesn't this question belong to http://codereview.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
L = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64] 
X = 5 
i = 0 
while i < len(L): 
    if 2 ** X == L[i]: 
        print('at index',i)
        break;
    i = i+1 
    if i==len(L): print(X,'not found')
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what i was looking for the only thing is does break count as a else clause?

Comment: to incorporate the else clause of the while statement, change the last line of code as 'else: print(X,'not found')'

Answer (score 1):

Python comes with [batteries](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Use the `index` method:

```
L = [...]
try:
    i = L.index(2**X)
    print("idex: %d"%i)
except ValueError as err:
    print("not found")
```

Comment: This is the way to do the job at hand, but this does not appear to be an answer to the question ("First, use an else while-loop clause,…")